# The command line is too long with mail() command

Tags: php

PHP is giving a The command line is too long Error when I use Mail();

```
<?php
$message = "Line 1";
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
mail('email@gmail.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

This code gives a The command line is too long error. Please help.

Comment: So, how long _is_ that `$message`?

Comment: It is just 'Line 1'

Comment: Seems ok for me. How you are running this code? Ain't it inserted into `exec` or `eval` function?

Comment: I Just load the code using chrome,by typing the file path in.