# php mail() error: "The command line is too long."

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am trying to make a mailing function in php, but I keep getting `the command line is too long` in the error file of xampp (error.ini). Below you find my script. I just configured the mailing function of Xampp. Could that be a possible reason? I know this is possibly a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58228638/the-command-line-is-too-long-with-mail-command) question BUT that question is unsanswered.

```php
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'email@example.com';
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n Here is the message:\n $message".
    
$to = "email@example.com";
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

header('Location: thank-you.html');

function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
   
?>
```

and the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>PHP form to email sample form</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="scripts/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>


<body>
    <form method="post" name="myemailform" action="form-to-email.php">
        <p>
            <label for='name'>Enter Name: </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for='email'>Enter Email Address:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="email">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for='message'>Enter Message:</label> <br>
            <textarea name="message"></textarea>
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit">
    </form>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        var frmvalidator = new Validator("myemailform");
        frmvalidator.addValidation("name", "req", "Please provide your name");
        frmvalidator.addValidation("email", "req", "Please provide your email");
        frmvalidator.addValidation("email", "email", "Please enter a valid email address"); 
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Look into SMTP, email server, and PHP Mailer. Why? Sending email from localhost still requires an email server or sometype of go between.

Comment: I have configured the mailing system in xampp (added SMTP, address, passsword...) so can you give some more clarification where I need to look (I am quite new and made this using a tutorial)

Comment: `mail()` is a low-level function that leaves to programmer most details about mail formatting to comply with SMTP specs. In the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) they explain that "lines should not be larger than 70 characters". It's very difficult to implement a protocol by your own. I highly recommend you try a third-party library that does the heavy lifting for you, such as PHPMailer or Swift Mailer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález sorry for the VERY late reaction, but still thanks for the response :)